# Распределение по xyz xyza и т.д.

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток!

У меня возник такой вопрос: как с помощью php реализовать распределение строк с цифрами по их элитности. Типа лесенка (12345) цифры подряд (111125) несколько пар (1116777) и т.п.

У меня есть построчный список типа:

```
1
2
3
```

В ручную более 10000 строк перебирать очень долго. Не особо получается вникнуть в такой алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Пример алгоритма, предложенного [[@Pavel Volyntsev](/users/19496/pavel-volyntsev)](/users/19496/pavel-volyntsev). Идея: присвоить каждому необходимому свойству свой коэффициент и умножать на него, допустим, число повторяющихся символов или число групп повторяющихся символов. Поиск последовательностей предлагаю написать вам самим.

```
<?php

$coeffs=array(
    'repeat'=>2, //повторы
    'mult_repeat'=>1.5 //несколько повторов
);

$data=file('nums.txt');
$result=array();
foreach($data as $num){
    $num=+$num; //чтобы убрать \r\n 
    $weight=0;    
    preg_match_all('((.)\1+)', $num, $matches); //поиск повторов
    //умножение на число групп повторов
    sizeof($matches[0]) && ($weight+=(sizeof($matches[0])-1)*$coeffs['mult_repeat']);
    //добавление общего числа повторов
    $weight+=array_sum(array_map('strlen', $matches[0]))*$coeffs['repeat'];
    $weight.=''; //конвертирование в строку
    //добавление в массив с полученной «элитностью» или его создание
    ($result[$weight]) || $result[$weight]=array();
    $result[$weight][]=$num;
}
krsort($result, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($result as $weight=>$nums){
    echo $weight.' '.join(', ', $nums)."\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае нужна функция, которая вычислит "элитность" числа. Она должна вернуть эту "элитность" в виде действительного или натурального числа. И пусть минимальное число = 0 - это совершенно не элитное число.

Придумай алгоритм вычисления "элитности". Реализуй в виде функции. Вычисли "элитность" для всех чисел. Выстроить их в порядке убывания. Возьми те, у которых "элитность" максимальная или близка к ней.